# Amplifying a Piezo with an Op-Amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, piezo

I am trying to use a piezo as a speaker.

(*I know that a piezo has a bad frequency-response. However, In my application it is better to use one instead of a speaker, since normal speakers don't like to be covered in gel.*)

Since a piezo is so much softer than a normal speaker, I want to amplify the signal. After looking for some tutorials on the internet, I found that i should be possible to use an Op-Amp connected in the Non-inverting Amplifier way. I bought a [LM324 Op-Amp](http://376458112.r.cdn77.net/sites/default/files/imagecache/Original/wysiwyg_imageupload/4214/LM324.jpg) to use in this circuit.
The 2.5mm jack is the plug that is used in most computer headphones.

Here is my curcuit, as connected on my protoboard:

[image: Circuit]

This does not seem to do any amplification of the signal. So I must have connected something wrong, or maybe my understanding of the different parts involved is incorrect. I hope someone can point the problem out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got the non-inverting amplifier wrong. See for example this image from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Op-Amp_Non-Inverting_Amplifier.svg):

[image: Circuit]

Note that the feedback goes to the negative input of the op-amp.